# making hash of hash

Tags: perl, design-patterns, hash

I have a file with different lines , each line has a repeated pattern.I need a propper data structure to parse my file for example:

```
cluster1:gene1(genome1) gene2(genome2) gene3(genome3)
cluster2:gene4(genome4) gene5(genome5)
```

*names are arbitary can be any thing .*

I have thought a bout a hash of hash data structure

```
  %hoh=("cluster1" => {
        "gene1"=>"genome1"
        "gene2"=>"genome2"
        "gene2"=>"genome2"
                       },   "cluster2" => {
        "gene4"=>"genome4"
        "gene5"=>"genome5"
                       }
       )
```

I have 2 questions:
first:how do I look for repeated pattern in each line ?

Second ,how do I make hash of hashe?

EDIT: Posted upon Zaid's request

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict; use warnings;
    my %HoH;
while(<DATA>){
    my $line=$_;
    chomp($line);
    my ( $cluster, $genes ) = split (/:/,$line);

     $HoH{ $cluster } = { split/[( )]+/ , $genes };

  }  
foreach $cluster (keys %HoH){
    print "$cluster: ";
    foreach $genes (keys %{$HoH{$cluster}}){
        print "$genes = $HoH{$cluster}{$genes} ";
    }
    print "\n";
}                                               

__DATA__
cluster1:gene1(genome1) gene2(genome2) gene3(genome3)
cluster2:gene4(genome4) gene5(genome5)
```

Comment: Will the pattern always follow `AAA:BBB(CCC) DDD(EEE) FFF(GGG)...`?

Comment: Have a look at [`perldoc perldsc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#HASHES-OF-HASHES). Oh, and [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I have written some parts , but its  a bit mess , so I decided not to put the code in here

Comment: In each line I can fetch first pattern I mean for exmaple in first line gene1 and genome 1 but dont know how to go further for finding the rest and insert them as key and value in a hash

Comment: @shaq : Do show us whatever you have and we'll be glad to help

Comment: are you sure BioPerl (http://www.bioperl.org) cannot deal with this format?

Comment: `while( my $line = <DATA> ){...}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Explanation to follow when OP posts their attempt:

```
my %HoH;

while (<>) {

    chomp;
    my ( $cluster, $genes ) = split /:/;

    $HoH{ $cluster } = { split /[( )]+/, $genes };
}
```

Comment: +1 Of course you don't have to split by space and parens separately since you'll end up with alternating keys and values. Much nicer than my ugly bit.

Comment: Better use `/[( )]+/` or the output of `split` will have some empty elements.

Comment: @ziad$HoH{ $cluster } = { split /[( )]+/, $genes }; this line has a problem I don't know what but after inserting this line the rest of my code is become like comment

Comment: @shaq : What do you mean by "become like comment"?

Comment: @ziad like we have an unclosed quote

Comment: @shaq : There is no way I can tell why it's not working for you if I don't see code. And have you enabled `use strict; use warnings;`?

Comment: @shaq : Remove the `my` in front of `$HoH{$cluster}` and put a `my %HoH;` above the `while` loop

Comment: @zias:for printing elements I have added some lines,it complains

Comment: @shaq : In the printing, `foreach $cluster {` should be `foreach my $cluster {`. Same for `$genes`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the pattern always follows `AAA:BBB(CCC) DDD(EEE) FFF(GGG)...`, you can use the following algorithm:

1. Read each line
2. Split on `:`, read the first part as your key
3. Split the remainder by spaces, then use a regex to parse, something like:  `([^(]+)\(([^)])\)`
4. Create the inner hash from the captured groups in the regex
5. Set `$hoh{key from step 2}` = the hash from step 4

Untested but something like the following (the hash reference thing is a bit iffy but you get the idea):

```
while(<>) {
    ($key, $rest) = split ':';
    @genes = split ' ', $rest;
    my %h;
    foreach $gene (@genes) {
        ($k, $v) = split /[\(\)]/, $gene;
        $h{$k} = $v;
    }
    $hoh{$key}=\%h;        
}
```

There's probably a more elegant PERL-y way to do this though :)

Comment: You should write code that is `strict` compliant, using lexical variables defined with `my`, e.g. `my ($key, $rest) = ...`

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict; use warnings;
    my %HoH;
    while(<DATA>){
        my $line=$_;
        chomp($line);
        my ( $cluster, $genes ) = split (/:/,$line);

        $HoH{ $cluster } = { split/[( )]+/ , $genes };

    }  
    foreach my $cluster (keys %HoH){
        print "$cluster: ";
        foreach my $genes (keys %{$HoH{$cluster}}){
            print "$genes = $HoH{$cluster}{$genes} ";
        }
    print "\n";
    }
```

__DATA__

cluster1:gene1(genome1) gene2(genome2) gene3(genome3)

cluster2:gene4(genome4) gene5(genome5)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't need to worry about lines that don't match your expected input, you can get away with a single [`split`](http://p3rl.org/split).

```
while( <DATA> ){
  chomp;
  next unless $_; # skip blank lines

  my($key,%value) = split /[:()\s]+/;
  $data{$key} = \%value;
}
```

Comment: I have got a problem , in my file I have 1 line(just for test)but it complains that use of uninitialized value $key in hash element line (x),in file line 2